# Comparing recursive Fibonacci with recursive factorial

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, factorial

This is the exercise 2.3.2 from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick and Wayne:

Write a recursive function that takes an integer n as its argument and returns ln(n!).

I wrote a recursive method in Java as follows:

```
public static double lnFactorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    return Math.log(n) + lnFactorial(n-1);
}
```

and it works perfectly fast with n up to approximately 10000. But the same-looking recursive method (below) for computing the nth Fibonnaci number takes forever to calculate the 50th Fibonnaci number for example.

```
public static  long fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    if (n == 2) return 1;
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

Why is there such a huge difference? Is it because the recursive method for Fibonacci calls itself two times in each iteration? Still I cannot comprehend the difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method calls itself recursively *once*, therefore the complexity is *O(n)*. The second method calls itself recursively *two times*, so per recursion depth the amount of calls is doubled, which makes the method *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

The difference between *O(n)* and *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* is gigantic, which makes the second method way slower.

Calculating the 50th number using the second method requires *2<sup>50</sup> = 1125899906842624* recursive calls. Using the first method requires just *50* recursive calls. (*Note:* Those numbers must not be exact. I've just added them to illustrate the magnitudes of the linear and the exponential approach.)

The important thing to understand here is that the second method calculates the fibonacci number of same *n*s multiple times. Look at the initial call that calls itself recursively with *n - 1* and *n - 2*. When you look at the call with *n - 1*, you see that it calls itself with *n - 2* and *n - 3*. Have you noticed the problem? The method got called with *n - 2* two times already. It has even called itself with *n - 3* two times already, when you look at the first call with *n - 2*. This will get worse and worse as the depth of the recursion increases.

Note that the first method doesn't call itself two times with any same value.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fibonacci method has a time complexity of *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* (see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-recursive-fibonacci-program/) explanation), while your factorial method has a time complexity of *O(n)*.

**Example** to understand time complexity:

Imagine a classroom of 100 students in which you gave your pen to one person. Now, you want that pen. Here are some ways to find the pen and what the O order is.

*O(n<sup>2</sup>)*: You go and ask the first person of the class, if he has the pen. Also, you ask this person about other 99 people in the classroom if they have that pen and so on,
This is what we call *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

*O(n)*: Going and asking each student individually is *O(n)*. ([source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-time-complexity-simple-examples/))

Edit: Example of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* is not the same as *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*. It's just an example about what time complexity means.

Comment: Fibonacci is _O(2ⁿ)_, not _O(n²)_, and that is what the link you provided says too.

Comment: Sorry, i'm more used to O(n²) so it was a bit without thinking. I've edited it.

Comment: @JipHarthoorn So how should we change the above example to illustrate the O(2ⁿ)?

Comment: @XBaghizadeh O(2ⁿ) denotes an algorithm whose growth doubles with each addition to the input data set. This means that with the pen example in mind, it would mean that for every person you ask, you would have to ask about one other person aswell. After that you ask the next person, where you would also have to ask about two other persons, which keeps getting doubled. But I'm not 100% sure if this is a valid example.